# Having an issue with my contacts on my Blackberry Priv

Tags: contacts, sim-card, google-contacts

I just got a Blackberry Priv, coming from a Blackberry Classic, both on AT&T. They imported my contacts from the old phone and they seemed to have moved onto my Google account. But for some reason the majority of my contacts don't have any information associated with them, just the names. When I go into my contacts list I see all the names, but most of them don't have any numbers. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to which came over with numbers and which didn't.

What is really weird is that when a contact that doesn't have a number associated with it texts/calls me I still see the correct name come up. For example, I don't have Kevin's number listed in my contacts, but when Kevin texts me it shows up as Kevin just fine. And even weirder yet, when I click on the "People and options" selection in the text thread it brings up a contact card with Kevin and his number.

Any idea's what the issue could be? How can I get my contacts with their numbers back?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't have the answer but suggest you ask at http://supportforums.blackberry.com. The PRIV also comes with 12 months of complimentary support as per https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/PRIV/Need-PRIV-Support-Call-us/td-p/3167154. Call 1-866-533-8067 (Canada & United States), or 0800-141-3330 (United Kingdom) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me was to open contacts and choose `all contacts` (top left 3 bars - Action Overflow brings up a menu where you can choose which list of contacts to use). My Priv was only using a subset of the contacts.